# Heaven and Earth are the work of whose hands according to Psalm 8:6 Hebrews 1:10-13; 2:5-8?

Tags: jesus, hebrews, creation

Hebrews 1:10-13; 2:5-8 YLT

> and, 'Thou, at the beginning, Lord, the earth didst found, and a work of thy hands are the heavens; these shall perish, and Thou dost remain, and all, as a garment, shall become old,  and as a mantle Thou shall roll them together, and they shall be changed, and Thou art the same, and Thy years shall not fail.'  And unto which of the messengers said He ever, 'Sit at My right hand, till I may make thine enemies thy footstool?'

Hebrews 2:5-8 YLT

> <sup>5</sup> For not to messengers did He subject the coming world, concerning which we speak, <sup>6</sup> and one in a certain place did testify fully, saying, ‘What is man, that Thou art mindful of him, or a son of man, that Thou dost look after him? <sup>7</sup> Thou didst make him some little less than messengers, with glory and honour Thou didst crown him, and didst set him over the works of Thy hands, <sup>8</sup> all things Thou didst put in subjection under his feet,’ for in the subjecting to him the all things, nothing did He leave to him unsubjected, and now not yet do we see the all things subjected to him,

Psalm 8:6

> Thou dost cause him to rule Over the works of Thy hands, All Thou hast placed under his feet.

Who is the antecedent for the pronoun "He" in  Hebrews 1:13?

Comment: This should be three separate questions.

Comment: Unless you left out what mattered, how is 'Thou, Lord…' not sufficient unto itself?

Answer (score 2):

Hebrews 1:10-13 New King James Version

> 13 But to which of the angels has **He** ever said:
>
> “Sit at My right hand, Till I make Your enemies Your footstool”?

1. In Hebrews 1:10-13, the author is quoting from Psalm 102:25-27

Psalm 102:25-27 is a prayer addressed to God. The author of Hebrews applies these verses to Jesus. The goal is demonstrating Jesus' divine authority and eternal nature.

In Hebrews 1:10-13, **the antecedent for the pronoun "He" in verse 13 is God mentioned in verse 1.**

A major "theme" in Hebrews is to present Jesus as the exalted Son of God, superior to all created beings, and co-creator with God. Therefore, based on the context and the author's application of the passage, I think we can say that the antecedent for the pronoun "He" in Hebrews 1:13 is the God the Father, speaking to Jesus the Son.

Allow me to quote [The Bible Says:](https://thebiblesays.com/commentary/heb/heb-1/hebrews-110-12/)

> These verses, quoting Psalm 102:25–27 and Isaiah 51:6, **refer to the
> unchanging and steadfast nature of the Son:** “**You, Lord [the Son]**, in
> the beginning laid the foundation of the earth, and the heavens are
> the works of Your hands.” Everything in the heavens and earth are
> **works of the Son’s hands**, and even when they change, He remains the
> same. He is the Creator who spoke the heavens and earth into
> existence. He is currently sustaining them, and at His word, the
> heavens and the earth will pass away:
>
> “They will perish, but You remain; And they all will become old like a
> garment, And like a mantle You will roll them up; Like a garment they
> will also be changed” (vv 11–12).

---

Jesus is the recipient of the statements made by God the Father.
Lets look at it closely! (This is how I believe it is to be read)

Hebrews 1:8-14 NKJV (Jesus, as the recipient of the statements made by God the Father.)

> 8 But *to the Son He says:* **[God Speaking]**
>
> “Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** throne, *O God* **[God calling Jesus God]**, is forever and ever; A scepter of
> righteousness is the scepter of Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]**  kingdom. 9 You **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** have loved
> righteousness and hated lawlessness; Therefore God **[Jesus]**, Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** God **[speaks of the Father and His position of authority over the Son]**, has
> anointed You With the oil of gladness more than Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** companions.”
>
> 10 And:
>
> “You, Lord **[[referring to the Son, Jesus] the Son is not only called God, but also Lord]**, in the beginning laid the foundation of the earth, And the
> heavens are the work of Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** hands. 11 They will perish, but You **[referring to the Son, Jesus]**
> remain; And they will all grow old like a garment; 12 Like a cloak You **[referring to the Son, Jesus]**
> will fold them up, And they will be changed. But You **[referring to the Son, Jesus]**  are the same, And
> Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]**  years will not fail.”
>
> 13 But to which of the angels has He **[God the Father said things never said to angelic beings to Jesus the Messiah.]** ever said:
>
> “Sit at My right hand **[God the Father's right hand - Jesus is invited sit at the right hand of God the Father.]**, Till I make Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** enemies Your **[referring to the Son, Jesus]** footstool”?
>
> 14 Are they not all ministering spirits sent forth to minister for
> those who will inherit salvation?

[Enduring word commentary says:](https://enduringword.com/bible-commentary/hebrews-1/)

> **(8-12) Jesus is superior to the angels because the Father Himself
> calls Him (and not any angel) God and LORD (Yahweh), as shown in Psalm
> 45:6-7 and 102:25-27 from the Septuagint.**
>
> a. But to the Son He says: Again, the emphasis is that God the Father
> says things to God the Son that are never said to angelic beings.
>
> b. Your throne, O God: Psalm 45:6-7 plainly says that God the Father
> calls the Son God. When the First Person of the Trinity spoke to the
> Second Person of the Trinity, He called Him God. This is unique and
> powerful evidence of the deity of Jesus.
>
> If
> Jesus is not the true God, He is a false god, like Satan and the
> wicked judges of Psalm 82.
>
> ii. But Jesus is the True and Living God, called so here by God the
> Father; and also by John in John 1:1, by Thomas in John 20:28, and by
> Paul in Titus 2:13 and Titus 3:4.
>
> c. Therefore God, Your God, has anointed You: This passage shows
> striking interaction between the Persons of the Trinity. “God, Your
> God” speaks of the Father and His position of authority over the
> Second Person of the Trinity. “You” refers to the Son. “Anointed” has
> in mind the ministry and presence of the Holy Spirit, the Third Person
> of the Trinity.
>
> d. You, LORD, in the beginning: Psalm 102:25-27 shows that the Son is
> not only called God, but also LORD (Yahweh). Then the Son is described
> with attributes and terms that belong only to God.
>
> i. You, LORD, in the beginning laid the foundation of the earth: This
> shows that Jesus Christ, the Second Person of the Trinity, is the
> Creator. Yahweh is specifically said to be the Creator (Isaiah 45:12,
> Isaiah 45:18).
>
> ii. They will perish, but You will remain: This shows that Jesus
> Christ, the Second Person of the Trinity is self-existent, even as
> Psalm 102:25-27 says this of Yahweh.
>
> iii. Like a cloak You will fold them up, and they will be changed:
> This shows that Jesus Christ, the Second Person of the Trinity is
> sovereign, with authority over all creation and history, even as Psalm
> 102:25-27 says this of Yahweh.
>
> iv. You are the same: This shows that Jesus Christ, the Second Person
> of the Trinity is immutable, unchanging, and eternal (Your years will
> not fail). Psalm 102:25-27 says this of Yahweh and the writer to the
> Hebrews says that it clearly applies to Jesus as well.
>
> **4. (13-14) Jesus is superior to the angels because He sat down, having completed His work, while the angels work on continually, as shown in Psalm 110:1.**
>
> a. But to which of the angels has He ever said: Now for the seventh
> time in this chapter, the writer to the Hebrews quotes the Hebrew
> Scriptures to demonstrate that Jesus the Messiah is far superior to
> any angelic being. He quoted Psalm 110:1 to show again that God the
> Father said things to Jesus the Messiah never said to angelic beings.
>
> b. Sit at My right hand: Psalm 110:1 says that the Messiah has this
> exalted place and posture in heaven. Anyone who sits in the divine
> presence shows that they have the perfect right to be there. There are
> no seats for the angels around the throne of God, because they are
> constantly busy praising God and serving Him. Yet Jesus can – at the
> invitation of God the Father – sit at the right hand of God the
> Father.

Comment: @Jason. If He in verse 13 is the Father, how could it be Jesus in verse 10?

Comment: @NigelJ I am clarifying with the contributor Jason_ his answer where his answer says "is fairly clear that the antecedent for the pronoun "He" in Hebrews 1:13 is the Lord, referring to Jesus Christ" . If the pronoun "He" in Hebrews 1:13 is the Father,  how can the antecedent be Jesus in Hebrews 1:10?

Comment: We all make mistakes.

Comment: @Jason_ Iam thankful for your answer. God has now appointed Jesus over these "works of His hands"  . The "work of His Hands" phrase that appear in Hebrews 1:10 Hebrews 2:7 and  Psalm 8:6 are not the hand of Jesus. Reexamine them again,  and see if they substantiate your conclusion.

Comment: @AlexBalilo (I speak from the view of a trinitarian) In these passages, the phrase "works of Your hands" refers to the creation of the universe and humanity by God. That's true. However, in Hebrews 1:10, the author applies these phrases to Jesus, indicating His role in creation as the Son of God. In the same way, Hebrews 2:7 emphasizes Jesus' exalted position over creation, indicating that God has appointed Him over the works of His hands. Jesus hadn't come yet so of course they don't outright say Jesus, but I believe that the author is applying these verses to Jesus. (See Colossians 1:16)

Comment: @Jason_. I respect your position. If the He in Hebrews 1:13 is the Father, then the antecedent could not be a different person.  If Jesus is the Almighty Creator of the bible,  the prophets patriarch never wrote about Jesus being the Creator. So how can you account for God Jesus  absence in the Old Testament.. That absence becomes clear if you read Hebrews 1:1-2 where it says God, having in the past spoken to the fathers through the prophets at many times and in various ways, has at the end of these days spoken to us by his son whom he appointed heir of all things, through whom he also made th

Comment: Absent ? There in the beginning, there in the garden, there with Job, represented to Abraham, wrestled with Jacob, there in the bush, captain of the host, rising up in the flame, present in the furnace, known of David . . . . .  can you not see Him ?

Comment: When Jesus taught in public as Mark 12:26 show, Jesus never claimed he was the God that told Moses I am the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac and the God Jacob, 27 God (not Jesus) is the God of the living. That is why the apostles and their disciples did not teach that Jesus is the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, Jesus is God's servant. Acts 3:13

Comment: @AlexBalilo Perhaps this is a doctrinal differentiation? I don't disagree with either Nigel J or Dottard's answer. I'd love to improve my answer if I can.

Answer (score 2):

God, who at sundry times ... verse 1.

For unto which, said he ... verse 5.

And again when he bringeth ... he saith ... verse 6.

But unto the Son ... 'Thy throne, O God ...' verse 8.

But to which said he at any time ... 'Sit ...' verse 13.

The antecedent of the pronoun 'he' in verse 13 is 'God' at the beginning of verse 1.

---

'Thy throne, O God ...' in verse 8 ; and 'Thou Lord ...' in verse 10 ; are both addressed to the same person ('Son' in verse 1) by Him who is called 'God' in verse 1.

Comment: I think you may have made a grammatical slip in your final sentence.  Throughout chapter 1 there is clear distinction between God [the Father] and the Son.  So, do you mean "by Him [ie the Father] called "God" in V8 & 9?

Comment: 'God' addresses 'Son' and says 'Thy throne, O God' and also says 'Thou, Lord, in the beginning' : is my understanding of the passage. I do not understand what the 'grammatical slip' is . The word 'Father' is not used in the passage. It is, in my own view, God the Spirit who speaks to the Son and says 'God even thy God hath anointed thee ...' (meaning the Father).

Comment: I fully agree.  I was pointing out that your last sentence reads as if Jesus is the "God" is V1 what cannot be true.

Comment: @Dottard I think I see the ambiguity now. And I have edited. Does that seem right to you now ?

Comment: Thanks, Nigel.  (I always agreed with your point!)

Comment: @NigelJ. The nearest antecedent for the pronoun "He" at verse 13 is "the Lord" of verse 10. The "He" in verse 13 is the Father this means "the Lord" of verse 10 is also the Father..

Comment: @AlexBalilo I disagree as a matter of both grammar and concept.

Answer (score 2):

Let me set this out by verse number in Heb 1

1. ... God [the Father] spoke ...
2. ... in these last days He [the Father] has spoken ...
3. The Son is ... He [the Son] sat down ...
4. So He [the Son] became ...
5. For to which of the angels did God [the Father] ever say: “You [the Son] are My [Father's] Son; today I [the Father] have become Your [the Son's] Father” ...
6. And again, when God [the Father] brings His firstborn [the Son] into the world, He  [the Father] says
7. Now about the angels He [the Father] says...
8. But about the Son He [the Father] says: "Your [the Son's] throne, O God, endures forever ...
9. You [the Son] have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; therefore God [the Son], Your God [the Father], has anointed You [the Son] above Your companions with the oil of joy.”
10. [continuing from V8] And, “In the beginning, O Lord [the Son], You [the Son] laid the foundations of the earth, and the heavens are the work of Your [the Son's] hands.... [This quotes Ps 102:25-27 which is about Jehovah and is applied to the Son; ie, the author of Hebrews is ascribing Ps 102:25-27 to Jesus as Jehovah.
11. Same as above
12. Same as above
13. Now to which of the angels did He [the Father] ever say: "Sit at My right hand, until I may place Your [the Son's] enemies as a footstool for Your [the Son's] feet"?

**Heb 2:5-8**

> For it is not to angels that He [God the Father as per V4] has subjected the world to come, about
> which we are speaking. But somewhere it is testified in these words:
>
> “What is man that You [God the Father] are mindful of him, or the Son of Man [Jesus] that You
> care for him? You [God the Father] made him a little lower than the angels; You crowned
> him with glory and honor and placed everything under his feet.”

This passage is quoting Ps 8:4-6 and applies it to Jesus during His incarnation (the "kenosis") as described in Phil 2:5-11.

Comment: This might be the most clear way it could have been put! +1